# Dynamic add servlet in WebLogic 12c not work?

Tags: weblogic, servlet-3.0, weblogic12c

I have two servlets below and work well with Tomcat7/Indigo,
it will print ' is added' when I visit myhost/DynamicAddServlet/tobeadded.jsp.

But they do not work in WebLogic 12c, is this possible in WebLogic 12c?

AddServletServlet

```
    package test.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name="AddServletServlet", urlPatterns={"/add.jsp"},
loadOnStartup=1)
public class AddServletServlet extends HttpServlet {
/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8873939883201271898L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dn =
                this.getServletContext().addServlet("TobeAddedServlet", TobeAddedServlet.class);
            dn.setAsyncSupported(true);
            dn.addMapping("/tobeadded.jsp");
            System.out.println(" ... init ...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

TobeAddedServlet

```
package test.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TobeAddedServlet extends HttpServlet {
/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8873939883201271898L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(" is added");
    }
}
```

the stacktrace in WebLogic 12c:

```
    <Mar 2, 2012 5:56:09 PM CST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1330682169014" for task "2". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "AddServletServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "DynamicAddServlet".
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: [HTTP:101388]The ServletContext was passed to the ServletContextListener.contextInitialized method of a ServletContextListener that was neither declared in web.xml or web-fragment.xml, nor annotated with javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.checkNotifyDynamicContext(WebAppServletContext.java:3834)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.addServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:3464)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.addServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:3564)
    at test.servlets.AddServletServlet.init(AddServletServlet.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:638)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:579)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)"
```

Thanks in advance,

Hippo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Servlet specification (point 4.4) You can execute method `addServlet` only from `contextInitialized` method of a `ServletContextListener` implementation or from the `onStartup` method of a `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation.

[Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, also found another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490648/adding-a-dynamic-servlet-using-servlet-3-0-throws-exception