# How to remove/replace an ServletRegistration?

Tags: servlet-3.0

Is it possible to replace a ServletRegistration via servlet-api?

Following code can only register new Servlets for the given servlet name, but if a servlet with the name exist, it does nothing.

```
ServletContext.addServlet( "servletName", ServletClass.class );
```

So I'm searching for a possibility to replace the registration (other ServletClass by same name) or to remove one by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facility to add servlets is provided during servlet context initialization.
Given that [it is impossible to add new servlets at runtime i.e. anytime after the Servlet Context is initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4491363/1733060), you should add the correct set of servlets during the servlet context initialization.

There is really no point in adding one servlet with a name and then replacing it with another servlet, all inside the servlet context initialization. Isnt it ? 
Do you see any use-case for it ?

@Balusc actually suggests a [good alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4491363/1733060) :

```
a single controller servlet in combination with command pattern is much better suited. 
You could then add commands (actions) during runtime and intercept on it based on the request URI.
```

Comment: Our use-case is a changed configuration (servlet behavior) for testing. The Application itself register its servlets with the ServletContextListener and a (test)submodule should overwrite the servlet implementation. (in servlet context initilisation process)
But ok, if its impossible we must try other solutions.
Thank you